# Enforcing flow annotations for function parameters

Tags: flowtype

How do I configure Flow to require type annotations for function parameters?

Specifically, I'd like Flow to show an error in the following code because params is not typed: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Types are inferred from usage. If this is an exported function then I recommend you use the types-first mode if you haven't already which enforces all module boundaries to have their types defined.

https://medium.com/flow-type/types-first-a-scalable-new-architecture-for-flow-3d8c7ba1d4eb

```
export function findOne(param) {

}
```

This will now throw an error and you must define the types of your function in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-flowtype) and configuring `require-parameter-type` rule

> Requires that all function parameters have type annotations